# Is there any DB server which could support following operations?

Tags: database, bigdata

I need to store a list of strings as field along with the Id: `listId, <list>`. 
Now I need following operations in order O(1) time:-

1. **Removing** a given string from an existing listId.
2. **Adding** a new string in an existing listId.

Is there any DB which could support above operations? Having HashSet as one of its datatype would help. Note that I need a highly scale-able solution where list could have 10Mn keys in 1000+ listIds.

I understand that such datatype if exists in any database would have considerable indexing overhead. I believe that chances are really slim for something similar to exist. If not, then I would implement something myself.

Comment: I request voter to explain the  downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps it was because strictly speaking, this is a resource request that is off topic on SO - or because storing a list of strings as a field in a table is generally really bad design, and the standard solution to this is to use [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and a separate table for the stuff you want to store in the blob. Choosing your database platform based on this requirement doesn't seem to make much sense - except if you have a specific reason?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the help. But I can't normalize a table with 10Mn fields. It means having 10Mn columns. But does that make sense? If not, then it means we can't have the said operations in any DB? 

I need another help, what would be best site on stackexchange to ask this question? I guess there must be something outside relational databases.

Comment: There's http://dba.stackexchange.com but check their FAQ first, I don't know what is on topic there and what isn't. I don't know what you mean by having 10 million columns though, in a 1:n relationship you'd have two tables and one of them might have 10 million or more *records* - which is nothing unusual. What you describe sounds like a textbook case for a 1:n relationship.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah I got it. I think I could design it now. I didn't need any datatype at all. I was designing it wrong. Thanks! Could you please post this as answer so I could accept and close the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a textbook case for [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You'd have two tables: one that contains the lists, and another that contains the list elements.

They are linked through the list ID:

Lists table:

```
id     name      (+ whatever else you need)
```

List elements table:

```
id     listId (connected to an id in the lists table)   (+ whatever else you need)
```